# Ruby require: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I installed the openbabel gem for Ruby, and get the message "successfully installed". But when I try requiring it, in, for example, IRB, I get the message:

```
LoadError: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/openbabel-
2.3.1.8/lib/openbabel/openbabel.so
```

When I do `ls -l` to this exact path, which I copy, then paste, what I get is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sselcuk None 11M Dec 30 23:44 openbabel.so*
```

I also checked this:

```
which ruby => /usr/bin/ruby
gem env|grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE' => /usr/bin/ruby
```

What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: What does "c/p" mean? I have never seen that abbreviation

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the setup you're using, you need to [require rubygems first](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4).

Example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'an_other_gem'
```

Comment: This is only true for Ruby < 1.9, maybe <1.8.7. I'm not at my computer to test it

Comment: Didn't know that!  Just tested it myself.  Thanks.

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3. didn't help anyway.